# Anyone could exlain width/height returned from iphone camera taken image on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, camera

I am using

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
  didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
      editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

to take the image. 
Then use

```
  CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

 CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
 CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
```

For some reason, the width always 640, and height always 480. no matter whether it is portrait or landscape.

I really confused on that, I thought in portraint, it should be width 320 and height is 480, while in landscape mode, width should be 480 and height should be 320.

What am I missing? How do I get correct width and height of the image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` is depreciated as of iOS 3.0.

Try using 
`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` 
and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The result is the same, the image size still 640 * 480.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    CGImageRef ref = image.CGImage;
    int width = CGImageGetWidth(ref);
    int height = CGImageGetHeight(ref);
    NSLog(@"image size = %d x %d", width, height);

    UIImage *orig = [editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    ref = orig.CGImage;
    width = CGImageGetWidth(ref);
    height = CGImageGetHeight(ref);
    NSLog(@"orig image size = %d x %d", width, height);

    CGRect origRect;
    [[editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerCropRect] getValue:&origRect];

    NSLog(@"Crop rect = %f %f %f %f", origRect.origin.x, origRect.origin.y, origRect.size.width, origRect.size.height);
}
```

For more discussion pease see: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7841245&tstart=0

Comment: This is the log output:   image size = 640 x 480
 orig image size = 0 x 0
 Crop rect = 0.000000 0.000000 0.207944 0.000000

Comment: are you getting the image from camera?

Comment: I got the image, I just can't handle the size properly.

Comment: OK if you are getting from camera/camera roll, I doubt that phone knows anything about orientation.

Comment: Seems [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] size.width and height gives proper way. It is 640 * 480 in landscape and 480 * 640 in portrait.